# Whether a matrix is a zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a real square matrix $A $ is similar to a diagonal matrix and satisfies $A^n=0$ for some $n\in \mathbb N $,then can it be proved that $A$ must be a zero matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

$$A\sim D:=\begin{pmatrix}a_1&0\\\ldots&\ldots\\0&a_n\end{pmatrix}\iff A=P^{-1}DP\implies$$

$$0=A^n=P^{-1}D^nP=P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}a_1^n&0\\\ldots&\ldots\\0&a_n^n\end{pmatrix}P\implies$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}a_1^n&0\\\ldots&\ldots\\0&a_n^n\end{pmatrix}=0\iff a_i=0$$

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Note that
$$
\left[S \pmatrix{\lambda_1\\&\ddots\\&&\lambda_k} S^{-1}\right]^n= 
S \pmatrix{\lambda_1^n\\&\ddots\\&&\lambda_k^n} S^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Hints:  If $A = S D S^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $S$ and diagonal matrix $D$, what can you infer about $D^n$ from the fact that $A^n = 0$?  (Solve for $D$ and compute its $n$-th power.)  What does that tell you about $D$, and what can you deduce about $A$?

Answer (score 3):

For a nonsingular matrix $X$, the map from the matrix ring $R\to R$ given by $M\mapsto X^{-1}MX$ is a ring automorphism. As such, it sends nilpotent elements to nilpotent elements.

If your $M$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$ via a similarity transformation like this, then $D$ is nilpotent too. What does a nilpotent diagonal matrix over a field look like?

After answering that, and remembering that $M\mapsto X^{-1}MX$ is an isomorphism, conclude  $M$ must be the zero matrix.

Answer (score 0):

A diagonalizable and nilpotent matrix is the null matrix. Why?

because first of all A can only have 0 as a possible eigenvalue, since its minimal polynomial (that is, the one that engenders the Ideal of polynomials such as, P(A) = 0 ) divides $X^n$.

Now since A is diagonalizable, there is a basis of eigen vectors of A, namely $(x_1,..,x_p )$ with p the size of your matrix.

Let X be a vector of $R^p$ : $ X = \sum_{k=1..p} b_k*x_k$

A*X = $ \sum_{k=1..p}b_k*A*x_k $ = $  \sum_{k=1..p}b_k*0 $ = 0

So A is the null matrix